# Vite build freeze on transforming... on dokku

Tags: vite, dokku

I have a Vite app that `vite build` works fine on local and building is successful on digitalocean Paas. but when I try to build the same app on dukku, it get stuck on `transforming...`

```
remote: -----> Cleaning up...        
remote: -----> Building app from herokuish        
remote: -----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...        
remote:        BUILD_ENV added successfully        
remote:        -----> Node.js app detected        
remote:                
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment        
remote:                
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error        
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false        
remote:        NODE_ENV=production        
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true        
remote:                
remote: -----> Installing binaries        
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified        
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)        
remote:                
remote:        Resolving node version 20.x...        
remote:        Downloading and installing node 20.11.0...        
remote:        Using default npm version: 10.2.4        
remote:                
remote: -----> Installing dependencies        
remote:        Installing node modules        
remote:                
remote:        added 786 packages, and audited 787 packages in 38s        
remote:                
remote:        144 packages are looking for funding        
remote:        run `npm fund` for details        
remote:                
remote:        42 vulnerabilities (37 moderate, 5 high)        
remote:                
remote:        To address issues that do not require attention, run:        
remote:        npm audit fix        
remote:                
remote:        Some issues need review, and may require choosing        
remote:        a different dependency.        
remote:                
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.        
remote:        npm notice        
remote:        npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.4 -> 10.5.0        
remote:        npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.0>        
remote:        npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.5.0` to update!        
remote:        npm notice        
remote:                
remote: -----> Build        
remote:        Running build        
remote:                
remote:        > app@0.2.0 build        
remote:        > run-p type-check build:only        
remote:                
remote:                
remote:        > app@0.2.0 type-check        
remote:        > vue-tsc --noEmit        
remote:                
remote:                
remote:        > app@0.2.0 build:only        
remote:        > vite build        
remote:                
remote:        vite v4.5.0 building for production...        
remote:        transforming...        
remote: Killed        
remote: ERROR: "type-check" exited with 137.        
remote:                
remote: -----> Build failed        
remote:                
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:        
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys        
remote:                
remote:        Some possible problems:        
remote:                
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json        
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version        
remote:                
remote:        Love,        
remote:        Heroku        
remote:                
remote:  !     Failure during app build        
remote:  !     Removing invalid image tag dokku/app:latest        
remote:  !     App build failed
```